# Stuck in an infinite loop when using while operation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

To crop a batch of images in tensorflow in parallel, I used those lines of code:

```
def cropImage(ind,input,output,d):
    input_t=input.read(ind)
    return ind+1,input,output.write(ind,tf.random_crop(input_t,d)),d
def image_crop(t,batchsize ,dims):
    c= lambda _ind,_1,_2,_3: control_flow_ops.math_ops.less(_ind, batchsize)
    ind = tf.Variable(0,'iter')
    output_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype='float32', size=batchsize,
        tensor_array_name="dynamic_crop_output")
    input_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype='float32', size=batchsize, 
        tensor_array_name="dynamic_crop_intput")
    input_ta.unpack(t)
    _1,_2,output,_3=control_flow_ops.While(c,cropImage,[ind,input_ta,output_ta,tf.constant(dims,name='dims')])
    o = output.pack()
    o.set_shape( [None] + list(dims))
    return o
```

My question is this one: if I don't put the instruction `o.set_shape( [None] + list(dims))` the program get stuck in what seems to be an infinite loop, Why?

Comment: Does this problem still occur in the latest version of TensorFlow? Since `o.set_shape()` only affects the return value, I suspect the problem is in some code that *calls* `image_crop()`, so can you share some of that code as well?

Comment: I have not that code anymore. Sorry for that.